# Split AC Unit for heating - Why shutdown when target is 22°C (71.6°F) but works fine when target is 24°C (75.2°F)

Tags: hvac

In one of my apartments I installed a split AC unit for heating. The floor space is about 20m2 while the unit is for about 100m2. (I intentionally oversized because there was not much of a price difference). Now one of my tenants complained that during cold weather (-5°C to 0°C (23°F to 32°F))  the unit will shut off if target is set to 22°C but works fine when target is 24°C. What could be the reason for this behavior? The only reason I could come up with is that when 22°C is set the temperature will be reached very fast causing the thermostat to shut the device off. Are there any other possible reasons? (The device was installed by a professional and is new so I assume no installation errors)

Comment: So, you intentionally oversized the unit by a factor of 5. Didn't exactly do your research...

Comment: Given that the insulation is very poor, the efficiency of the weaker model is about 30% lower and the fact that the model should be used to heat other rooms in the building (which at the moment are still under construction) it seemed like a reasonable choice..